# Creating a form in angular js using angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I keep getting this error:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module firstApplication due to:(…)

I tried naming firstApplication several different way but was unable to do so. I have a feeling its a simple solution but i cant seem to figure it out.

Here is my html

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" src="style.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v0.8.0/angular-material.js"></script> </head>

<body ng-app="firstApplication">
    <div data-ng-controller="ContactFormController as cf" flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <div flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="90" flex-gt-md="70" flex-gt-lg="50" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <form name="contactForm" data-ng-submit="cf.sendMail()">
                    <md-input-container>
                        <lable>Name:</lable>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="cf.contactName" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container>
                         <lable>Email</lable>
                        <input type="email" data-ng-model="cf.contactEmail" required> 
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container>
                         <lable>Message</lable>
                        <textarea data-ng-model="cf.contactMsg" columns="1" required></textarea>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary" ng-class="{'md-raised md-hue-1': (contactForm.$dirty && contactForm.$valid)}">Send</md-button>
                </form>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> </body>
```

Here is my Angular Code

```
'use strict'; angular.module('firstApplication', ['$scope','$mdToast', '$animate'])
          .controller('ContactFormController', ContactFormController);

         function ContactFormController ($scope, $mdToast, $animate) {
           $scope.toastPosition ={
            bottom: false,
            top:true,
            left: false,
            right:true
           };
           $scope.getToastPosition = function(){
                return Object.keys($scope.toastPosition)
                .filter(function(pos){
                    return $scope.toastPosition[pos];
                })
                .join(' ');
           };

           $this.sendMail = function(){
                $mdToast.show(
                    $mdToast.simple()
                        .content('Thanks for your message' + this.contactName +'You Rock')
                        .position($scope.getToastPosition())
                        .hideDelay(5000)
                );
           };

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. You have duplicate script references, you're referencing different versions of Angular libraries, your injection into the main Angular module is incorrect and you've used `$this` instead of `this` in your controller. Here is an updated snippet with these corrections made (I have not addressed what your code around the toast is trying to do because I'm not familiar with that):

```js
angular.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('ContactFormController', ContactFormController);

function ContactFormController($scope, $mdToast, $animate) {
  $scope.toastPosition = {
    bottom: false,
    top: true,
    left: false,
    right: true
  };
  $scope.getToastPosition = function() {
    return Object.keys($scope.toastPosition)
      .filter(function(pos) {
        return $scope.toastPosition[pos];
      })
      .join(' ');
  };

  this.sendMail = function() {
    $mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.simple()
      .content('Thanks for your message' + this.contactName + 'You Rock')
      .position($scope.getToastPosition())
      .hideDelay(5000)
    );
  };

};
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link type="text/css" src="style.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v0.8.0/angular-material.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="firstApplication">
  <div data-ng-controller="ContactFormController as cf" flex layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="90" flex-gt-md="70" flex-gt-lg="50" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form name="contactForm" data-ng-submit="cf.sendMail()">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="cf.contactName" required>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" data-ng-model="cf.contactEmail" required>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea data-ng-model="cf.contactMsg" columns="1" required></textarea>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary" ng-class="{'md-raised md-hue-1': (contactForm.$dirty && contactForm.$valid)}">Send</md-button>
        </form>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. The toast just leaves a message on top right of the screen with the persons name and says you rock !

Answer (score 0):

I see three bugs in your code:

1. You should reference `app.js` in `head`, not in the bottom of `body`
2. You should replace `angular.module('firstApplication', ['$scope','$mdToast', '$animate'])` with `angular.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])`
3. You should change `$this.sendMail = function(){` to `this.sendMail = function(){`

Moreover, you referenced

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

two times